# How to get ElasticSearch Aggregation with duration

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using ElasticSearch 7.1.0, and Kibana 7.1.0, and I have data that looks like the following

```
{
  "user":"8a195d1b-24c9-11e5-8f96-00142273155d",
   "session_id":"4d024a90-b141-4ee1-b4e3-e2022fb2f581",
   "timestamp":1559681962442,
   "recieved_timestamp":1559681964197,
   "feature_id":"foo",
   "dwell":{
      "resource_id":"foo",
      "dwell_ms":23218
   },
   "event_type":"dwell",
   "stored_timestamp":1559682046757
}
```

I want to have a view into the data using an aggregation that shows the start and stop of a dwell event, where I have used a terms aggregation to sort dwell events into buckets of what feature is being referenced, and then for each of the events in these buckets add the relative dwell offset to the timestamp so that I would have both a start and stop time for an event.

Any guidance on how to structure this type of query for elasticsearch would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I can't able to see any field as ```start``` & ```stop``` for your given event docs. Is it there?

Comment: @Suresh well the timestamp field is the start time and the stop is what I wanted to derive from time stamp and dwell.dwell_ms which is a relative duration

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It'll aggregate all events by field `event_type` & again use a `top_hits` sub aggregation to get the `timestamp` field from respective term aggregation bucket.

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "event_type": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "event_type",
                "size": 5
            },
            "aggs": {
                "top_event_hits": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "_source": {
                            "includes": [
                                "timestamp"
                            ]
                        },
                        "size": 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```